# How do i replace an image based on an if statement?

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote an if statement that will choose an icon based on the value of x being 1 or 0. The hlpTbl is a popup window that displays some helpful links and has icons next to them. Depending on whether they hit employee or manager, the icon should change to either documentIcon.gif or mgrIcon.gif.

The statement "imgpath + icon" is where the errors are coming for me. Any suggestions?

```
        function setHelpContent(ctntType){
            var numSects = mycontent.helpTitleArrSz;
            var numItems = 0;
            var hlpTbl = "<div class=\"closeBtn\" height=\"25px\"><a href=\"javascript: hidePopup();\" class=\"whtNavLinks\">[x]</a></div><table border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"3\" id=\"helpTbl\"class=\"helpTbl\">";

            for (x=0; x<=numSects; x++){
                hlpTbl = hlpTbl + "<tr id='helpTitle" + x + "'><td class='helpTitle'>" + mycontent["helpTitle_" + x] + "</td></tr>";
                hlpTbl = hlpTbl + "<tr><td><div align=\"center\" id=\"helpCtg_" + x +"\" class=\"hlpCtgDiv\"><table align=\"center\" class=\"hlpCtgTbl\">";

                if ( x == 0 ){
                    var icon = "documentIcon.gif\"
                    return icon;
                }
                else if ( x == 1 ){
                    var icon = "mgrIcon.gif\"
                    return icon;
                }

                for (i=0; i<=mycontent["helpContent" + x + "_Sz"]; i++){
                    hlpTbl = hlpTbl + '<tr class="helpItem" id="helpItemRow' + x + i + '" onmouseover="javascript: document.getElementById(\'helpItemRow' + x + i + '\').className = \'helpItemHiglight\';" onmouseout="javascript: document.getElementById(\'helpItemRow' + x + i + '\').className = \'helpItem\';" onclick="javascript: openWin(\'' + mycontent["helpContent_" + x + "_" + i + "_link"] + '\')"><td class="helpborder">';
                    hlpTbl = hlpTbl + "<img src=\"" + imgpath + icon class=\"docIconSmall\"/></a></td><td style=\"border-bottom: solid 1px; border-color: #8E88F7;\">";
                    hlpTbl = hlpTbl + "<div style=\"position: relative; left: 7px; width: 440px; text-align: left;\">" + mycontent["helpContent_" + x + "_" + i] + '</div></td></tr>';
                }
                hlpTbl = hlpTbl + "</div></table></td></tr>"
            }
            hlpTbl = hlpTbl + "</table><div>&nbsp;</div>"
            document.getElementById("popupTbl").innerHTML = hlpTbl;
            showPopup(contactsTbl_Class);
            expndBlock('helpCtg_' + ctntType,ctntType,numSects);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a missing + sign:

```
hlpTbl = hlpTbl + "<img src=\"" + imgpath + icon class=\"docIconSmall\"/></a></td><td style=\"border-bottom: solid 1px; border-color: #8E88F7;\">";
```

between the icon and class. Should be:

```
hlpTbl = hlpTbl + "<img src=\"" + imgpath + icon + " \"" + class=\"docIconSmall\"/></a></td><td style=\"border-bottom: solid 1px; border-color: #8E88F7;\">";
```

Comment: Hmmm still getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" when I inspect element in Chrome. I'm not really too sure why it's not just replacing the variable with the text.

This line works in the code perfectly fine if you don't use the if statement and just use straight up text instead of the var icon.


hlpTbl = hlpTbl + "<img src=\"" + imgpath + "documentIcon.gif\"  class=\"docIconSmall\"/></a></td><td style=\"border-bottom: solid 1px; border-color: #8E88F7;\">";

Comment: Add at the end of the loop block: console.log(hlpTbl) and see what it says.

Comment: I'm not getting any output for some reason.

Comment: it probably fails before that. Put a console.log before each statement.